# Commercial databases adept in storing biological sequences

Tags: database, dna-sequence, protein-database

Which commercial databases are adept in storing biological sequences like Protein/DNA sequence? Are there any which were designed specifically to store such sequences?

cheers

Answer (score 2):

One of the areas targetted by Oracle's 10g release was bioinformatics.  There is a summary of the relevant database features on the Oracle web site.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/industries/life_sciences/pdf/ls_briefing_in_bioinf_or10gdb.pdf).  It includes [support for BLAST](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/obe10gdb/bidw/blast/blast.htm) which I think is particularly relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's [BLASTgres](http://www.blastgres.org/) for [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), but I have no personal experience with it.